# Ordenar array por ela mesma dentro do indice em PHP

Tags: php, array

Estou trabalhando com o datatables, e por um acaso do destino resolvi usar a função `ajax` dele, fiz todo o processo, mas falta uma coisa, conseguir reordenar a array, pois usando de processamento `server-side` o `dataTables` não interage `client-side` para reordenar.

A array retornada é um `JSON` disso (aqui está na ordem, mas eu preciso poder alterar essa ordem como eu quiser):

```
$arr = [
     [
     'linha 1 coluna 1 valor z',
     'linha 1 coluna 2 valor b',
     'linha 1 coluna 3 valor h',
     'linha 1 coluna 4 valor d',
     'linha 1 coluna 5 valor e'
     ],    
     [
     'linha 2 coluna 1 valor b',
     'linha 2 coluna 2 valor c',
     'linha 2 coluna 3 valor r',
     'linha 2 coluna 4 valor i',
     'linha 2 coluna 5 valor l'
     ],    
     [
     'linha 3 coluna 1 valor q',
     'linha 3 coluna 2 valor w',
     'linha 3 coluna 3 valor y',
     'linha 3 coluna 4 valor u',
     'linha 3 coluna 5 valor s'
     ]
];
```

O que eu preciso, é poder ordenar a linha pelo valor de qualquer uma das colunas com base no valor que ela mesmo possui.

Não estou conseguindo achar a função que eu possa fazer isso, bem é essa dúvida:

> Como ordenar uma array quando não há indice e o valor é o proprio
>   indice da segunda dimensão ?

Exemplo de como ficaria caso eu recebesse o comando para ordenar pela coluna 1:

```
$arr = [ 
     [
     'linha 2 coluna 1 valor b',
     'linha 2 coluna 2 valor c',
     'linha 2 coluna 3 valor r',
     'linha 2 coluna 4 valor i',
     'linha 2 coluna 5 valor l'
     ],     
     [
     'linha 3 coluna 1 valor q',
     'linha 3 coluna 2 valor w',
     'linha 3 coluna 3 valor y',
     'linha 3 coluna 4 valor u',
     'linha 3 coluna 5 valor s'
     ],
     [
     'linha 1 coluna 1 valor z',
     'linha 1 coluna 2 valor b',
     'linha 1 coluna 3 valor h',
     'linha 1 coluna 4 valor d',
     'linha 1 coluna 5 valor e'
     ]
];
```

> ATUALIZAÇÃO

Consegui com uma gambiarra, mas ainda acho que deve haver um jeito mais bonito:

$ordergin = $var['order_rule'];

```
foreach ($records['data'] as $key => $row) {
    $order_company[$key] = $row[1];
    $order_cnpj[$key] = $row[2];
    $order_tax_regime[$key] = $row[3];
    $order_responsible[$key] = $row[3];
    $order_status[$key] = $row[5];
}

if ($ordering == 'order_by_resp_desc') {
    array_multisort($order_responsible, SORT_DESC, $records['data']);
} elseif($ordering == 'order_by_resp_asc'){
    array_multisort($order_responsible, SORT_ASC, $records['data']);
} 
//Seguindo daqui até todas as opções disponiveis de ordenamento
```

Comment: Tem como dar um exemplo de como ficariam esses dados após essa tal ordenação?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss coloquei na pergunta ali o exemplo, to tentando com array_multisort, mas ainda não achei o modo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com PHP 5.5.0 ou superior, você pode fazer uso da função [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-multisort.php) em conjunto com a [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php):

```
<?php

$arr = [['z', 'b', 'h', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'l'], ['q', 'w', 'y', 'u', 's']];

// Ordena $arr pelo valor da coluna 0:
array_multisort(array_column($arr, 0), SORT_ASC, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

<sup>Veja funcionando em [Ideone](https://ideone.com/F51GhJ) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MurE/0)</sup>

Resultando em:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => c
            [2] => r
            [3] => i
            [4] => l
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => q
            [1] => w
            [2] => y
            [3] => u
            [4] => s
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => z
            [1] => b
            [2] => h
            [3] => d
            [4] => e
        )

)
```

Com a função `array_column` você irá criar a ordem dos valores com base na coluna desejada e essa ordem será mantida na ordenação dos outros *arrays*, que é o próprio `$arr`.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um pequeno exemplo, utilizei a função arsort que já existe no php só para exemplificar, mas você pode escolher a que você quiser, este código vai funcionar se a ordenação ordena também os índices.

Basicamente ele faz o seguinte, verifica o índice do primeiro do array ordenado e ordena os outros naquelas posições:

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";

$arr = [
    [
        'linha 1 coluna 1 valor a',
        'linha 1 coluna 2 valor b',
        'linha 1 coluna 3 valor c',
        'linha 1 coluna 4 valor d',
        'linha 1 coluna 5 valor e'
    ],
    [
        'linha 2 coluna 1 valor f',
        'linha 2 coluna 2 valor g',
        'linha 2 coluna 3 valor h',
        'linha 2 coluna 4 valor i',
        'linha 2 coluna 5 valor j'
    ],
    [
        'linha 3 coluna 1 valor k',
        'linha 3 coluna 2 valor l',
        'linha 3 coluna 3 valor m',
        'linha 3 coluna 4 valor n',
        'linha 3 coluna 5 valor o'
    ]
];

print_r($arr);

//Indice que vai ser ordenado
$indiceOrdenado = 0;

//Função de ordenação
arsort($arr[$indiceOrdenado]);

//Ordena os outros indices de acordo com o indice ordenado
foreach ($arr as $index => $item) {
    if ($index == $indiceOrdenado) {
        continue;
    }
    $i = 0;
    reset($arr[$indiceOrdenado]);
    $temp = $arr[$index][key($arr[$indiceOrdenado])];
    foreach ($arr[$indiceOrdenado] as $indice => $sub_item) {
        $arr[$index][$indice] = $arr[$index][$i];
        $i++;
    }
    $arr[$index][0] = $temp;
}

print_r($arr);

echo "</pre>";
```

Array inicial:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => linha 1 coluna 1 valor a
            [1] => linha 1 coluna 2 valor b
            [2] => linha 1 coluna 3 valor c
            [3] => linha 1 coluna 4 valor d
            [4] => linha 1 coluna 5 valor e
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => linha 2 coluna 1 valor f
            [1] => linha 2 coluna 2 valor g
            [2] => linha 2 coluna 3 valor h
            [3] => linha 2 coluna 4 valor i
            [4] => linha 2 coluna 5 valor j
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => linha 3 coluna 1 valor k
            [1] => linha 3 coluna 2 valor l
            [2] => linha 3 coluna 3 valor m
            [3] => linha 3 coluna 4 valor n
            [4] => linha 3 coluna 5 valor o
        )

)
```

Array Final:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [4] => linha 1 coluna 5 valor e
            [3] => linha 1 coluna 4 valor d
            [2] => linha 1 coluna 3 valor c
            [1] => linha 1 coluna 2 valor b
            [0] => linha 1 coluna 1 valor a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => linha 2 coluna 5 valor j
            [1] => linha 2 coluna 2 valor g
            [2] => linha 2 coluna 3 valor h
            [3] => linha 2 coluna 2 valor g
            [4] => linha 2 coluna 1 valor f
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => linha 3 coluna 5 valor o
            [1] => linha 3 coluna 2 valor l
            [2] => linha 3 coluna 3 valor m
            [3] => linha 3 coluna 2 valor l
            [4] => linha 3 coluna 1 valor k
        )

)
```

Comment: Assim também da certo, só tem muitas verificações, o modo que o Anderson passou é mais limpo, mas mesmo assim desse modo também da certo!

Comment: Realmente, o do Anderson ficou melhor

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo a pergunta pra informar como ficou usando as respostas recebidas:

Recebendo os dados (passados pelo DataTables), e chamando uma função pra definir:

```
 $order_col = $_POST['order'][0]['column'];
 $order_dir = $_POST['order'][0]['dir'];
 $order_arr = self::get_order_dir($order_dir);
```

Função que define a ordem:

```
private static function get_order_dir($dir) {
    if ($dir == 'desc') {
        $rs['dir'] = SORT_DESC;
    } else {
        $rs['dir'] = SORT_ASC;
    }
    return $rs;
}
```

Fazendo o reordenamento com `'array_multisort'` de acordo com indice solicitado:

```
array_multisort(array_column($records['data'], intval($col)), $order_arr['dir'], $records['data']);
```